# `torch_geometric.nn.attention` not found in PyTorch Geometric Reference

Tags: python, pytorch-geometric

I was following an tutorial in the PyG repository, [GraphGPS](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/examples/graph_gps.py).

In the example there is a line:

```
from torch_geometric.nn.attention import PerformerAttention
```

Which caused an error:

```
Cannot find reference 'attention' in '__init__.py'
```

I browsed PyG's [documentation](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.conv.GPSConv.html#torch_geometric.nn.conv.GPSConv) again, on the left in package reference, I couldn't find `torch_geometric.nn.attention`:

[image]

How to resolve this problem? I have PyG 2.3.1 installed, and I had no issue running other layers like GCN. Do I need install additional packages?

Comment: I think it is because I have to update PyG to 2.4.0. Version 2.3.1 is no longer the latest version, the tutorial is written for 2.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2.4.0 to use `PerformerAttention`. Updating your PyG version should resolve your issue. To update the package, run:

```bash
pip install -U torch-geometric
```